# adding TTImageView to an XIB using Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, interface-builder, three20

I'm trying to add `TTImageView` to an `XIB` file by adding a regular `UIImageView` control then changing its class name to `TTImageView` in the Identity Inspector, but it can't recognize the class `TTImageView`, `IB` keeps reverting the class name to `UIImageView`. I have added `Three20` framework correctly to my project, what should I do to add `TTImageView` using `IB` ?

Comment: Any chance of getting a tick for my answer if it is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TTImageView` is derived from `UIView` not `UIImageView`.

You'll have to use a `UIView` in your XIB if you want to set it as a `TTImageView`.

See [here](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_image_view.php)